# Opportunity RecordType and Sales Process

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, dependent-picklist

If I want a picklist with the `Stagename` and the `Probability`, I can use the code below.

But how can I get a list of `RecordTypes` with the `Stagenames`?

```
public List <SelectOption> getProductList() {
    List<SelectOption> options =  new List<SelectOption>();    
    options.add(new selectOption('None','--- None ---'));    
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.RecordTypeId.getDescribe();    
    List<Schema.picklistEntry> vls = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();    
    for(Schema.picklistEntry v:vls)    
    {    
        options.add(new selectOption(v.getLabel(),v.getValue()));                    
    }
    RETURN options;    
}
```

Comment: Your question is quite vague.  You've posted the code for a picklist, and then asked for a list.  Which are you trying to create?  If you want a list of record types with stage names, how should the list look?  What code have you written so far?

Comment: I wrote the code above. I thought that I can take the Opportunity.RecordTypeId but it doesn't work. I mean also a picklist. For the StageName with the probability it works fine, but how is the process for the recordtype to the stagename / sales process.

Answer (score 1):

The `RecordTypeId` field is a lookup, not a picklist.

```
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
for (RecordType recordType : [
    SELECT Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity'
]) options.add(new SelectOption(recordType.Id, recordType.Name));
```